# How to set favicon.ico on a pdf link?

Tags: java, pdf, favicon

I am working on web project in java where i have to open a pdf file by the link :

`<a href="files/help.pdf" target="_blank" title="User Manual (pdf)">View User Manual</a>`

I know how to set `favicon` on the links but didn't know how to set it on this pdf file..

Can anyone have the answer?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

In Chrome, do the following:

1. Place the favicon in the root of your website, and call it favicon.ico
2. Clear the cache
3. Load the PDF from your website

Comment: i did the same, and found your later. this really works.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. A favicon is something that can be set on a HTML page, but not on a PDF file. You might be able to do that by linking to a HTML page which has a favicon and contains an iframe containing the PDF file, but it seems overkill for just a favicon.

Comment: Actually the bad thing is, it displays the Apache symbol at place of favicon, and if mine could not be there how can Apache's?

Comment: Probably because the root webapp (i.e. the webapp deployed on the root context, under /) has a default favicon. Just remove the ROOT directory from the webapps folder of your tomcat install, and you shouldn't see it anymore. Or just remove the favicon.ico from this ROOT folder. Or, as Bozho suggested, replace it with yours.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the default favicon location - i.e. place `favicon.ico` on the root of server (which is normally the ROOT application). In production you will almost always be running as ROOT. But I don't know if browsers will recognize that - if they don't, it means you can't do it. PDFs are read in the browser only if there's a plugin, so perhaps the normal favicon resolution doesn't happen.

Comment: didn't get what is actual mean of root?? Sorry...m newbee to java web..and currently working with Apache Tomcat and NetBeans

Comment: in your web application's root. Normally, tomcat/webapps/yourapp/. Or the folder where WEB-INF is placed.

Comment: well, then it is not supported. You can't do it

Comment: But i dont like the Apache's icon on the same pdf... Is it way to remove that one ? hahaha

Comment: @Bozho: for the browser, the root of the webapp doesn't constitute a root. It's just a subfolder of the root of the server. The OP should replace the ROOT's favicon with his own favicon. ROOT is the webapp deployed on the root, under /.

Comment: @JB Nizet, yup, true. I assumed he is running the root app, but obviously incorrectly. I'll fix my answer

Comment: I removed the favicon, i replaced it by mine, i removed the ROOT directory, i restarted the server every time, i reload my app everytime, but, nothing happens...it seems i should be happy with what i get with the hyperlinks and not to try it on pdf's... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a php script to deliver the pdf and setting a favicon in the header there.
But I don't think thats worth the effort.

Comment: Sure you can set that with a header? (besides, he's using java, not php)

Comment: Not sure at all, but it would be worth googling it